# How to show html form inside html list in q single line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show some list of data into HTML. While showing the data I have enclosed that data into form tag but while printing it not coming in a single line

**Input:-**

```
<ul id="myUL" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;list-style:none">
     {% for tagname in globalKeywordList%}
          <li style="display:inline;">
               <form action="searchKeyword/{{tagname}}" method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="mostRelevant" data-toggle=”button” value="mostRelevant" style="background-color:transparent;padding:0;margine:0">{{ tagname }}
               </button>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
               </form>
          </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Output:-**

[image]

As shown in the picture if the sentence is too long then it won't start from the previously closed data, some space is left blank and then started

***How to resolve that problem ??***

Comment: Hi Can you share your static content which is you hide in screenshot so I can reproduce realistic content on the web-page and also share your CSS if you are using any

Comment: See css media query since you need to styled for printing  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: the content inside the screenshot is not static, that data is dynamic which send by my python code and I haven't used any external CSS

Comment: @AlanM sorry I didn't get u?? how this media query will help me

Comment: You said 'printing'

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Add the css styling inside the style element of the html generates  file as a child element of the head parent element see this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp